# laravel 5.4 auth register custom error message

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, error-handling, eloquent

Im sorry i am new for laravel, but this is strange,

i want to use custom error message in validation of error register,
in my registercontroller :

```
$messages = [
        'vbadminEmail.required'      => 'Email has already been taken this is customize error.', 
    ];

    $result = Validator::make($data, [            
        'vbadminEmail' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:admin_user,user_email',
        'vbadminPassword' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ],$messages);
```

when i test and debug the result :

[debug the error arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQWWW.jpg)

it still used the general format, not the "Email has already been taken this is customize error"

please help me how to fix it
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
   $messages = [
    'vbadminEmail.unique'      => 'Email has already been taken this is customize error.', 
   ];
```

in your current code you are applying custom message on required rule, so you need to add custom message on unique rule not on required